# How to fix pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for CardView?

Tags: android

in my app i have added shared view transition on a image view which is inside a card view layout
but whenever i click on the recycler view item whose layout is the card view mentioned above it shows the following exception in stack trace

JNI CallObjectMethod called with pending exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for CardView

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Linear Layout instead of Cardview.

Also, did you try setting `android:transitionGroup="false`" in the rootview